# I have 55,000 rows of rental data to clean, the data is inconsistent and contains text and numbers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 55,000 rows of rental data, in one of the columns is the rent prices per week.

This column is not sanitized which has led to a nightmarish combination of numbers, text and phone numbers contained within these fields.

I am trying to extract just the weekly rental figure or return a blank cell if none is provided.

Code current employed below, which copies the column to another column and runs a series of find and replaces against this data. This is leading to about 75%/80% being perfect and the remainder being almost entirely useless (data is either butchered like the below image or contains items like $400$500 which still needs to be cleaned)

[image: filter list]

The above data contained the following text as an example of how its butchered:

[image: List]

```
Sub A_Core_Clean_Level_1()

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Rows("1:1").AutoFilter

Sheets("Rental Data").Range("I1").EntireColumn.Copy Range("R1").EntireColumn

Columns("R:R").Replace What:="1oo", Replacement:="100", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="2oo", Replacement:="200", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="3oo", Replacement:="300", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="4oo", Replacement:="400", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="5oo", Replacement:="500", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="6oo", Replacement:="600", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="7oo", Replacement:="700", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="9oo", Replacement:="800", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="9oo", Replacement:="900", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

Columns("R:R").Replace What:="1 day", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="2 days", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="3 days", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="4 days", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="5 days", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="6 days", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="7 days", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="8 days", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="9 days", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="10 days", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

Columns("R:R").Replace What:=".00*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="$ ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" $", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 1 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 2 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 3 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 4 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 5 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 6 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 7 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 8 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 9 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 10 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 11 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 12 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 13 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 14 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 15 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 16 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 17 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 18 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 19 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 20 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 21 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 22 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 23 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 24 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" 25 ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

Columns("R:R").Replace What:="a", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="b", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="c", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="d", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="e", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="f", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="g", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="h", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="i", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="j", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="k", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="l", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="m", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="n", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="o", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="p", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="q", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="r", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="s", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="t", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="u", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="v", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="w", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="x", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="y", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="z", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

Columns("R:R").Replace What:="..", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="&", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="+", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="/", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="!", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="|", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:="(", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=")", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
'Columns("R:R").Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
'Columns("R:R").Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Columns("R:R").Replace What:=" *", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

Rows("1:1").AutoFilter

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I believe the ideal outcome would be to extract circumstances where 3 or 4 consecutive numbers are found then work on code to clean the remainder using find and replace(s). While this would mean that where mobile/phone numbers are present; if they are first, they would still be included in the data captured, however it would be closer to cleaned.

Does anyone have any suggestions to clean this data within excel using either formula or code.

Comment: If you have Excel 2016 or later I suggest that you use [Power Query](https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/)

Comment: Instead of replacing everything you don't want why don't you grab what you do want. Is what you want from the column just the rent value? Will that always follow a `$` symbol and be 3 digits long or have a non-numeric value straight after the value you want? I can't say I've ever seen a wall of Replace commands like that before...

Comment: Yes, it will always start with a $ and be follow by a number of integers (3, 4 or 5) then be followed by either a space, a dash, a period or another non-integer, however the value will appear randomly within the string. This was my very ineffectively solution.

Comment: I don't suppose you could supply the data in question? Or at least some of it to test with.

Comment: Sure https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AABA2Hr8cAO7VtQES7FiHXYcByK_9naGpSY

Comment: I added my answer below. For the amount of rows you say you have it's probably a better solution as it stops you having that many regular formulas sitting in your sheet which can slow things down.

Comment: text to columns using delim '$' followed by " ", should give some worthwhile results imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for a User Defined Function (UDF). Here is a prototype.

```
Function Rental(Cell As Range) As Variant

    Dim CellVal As String           ' Cell's contents
    Dim p       As Integer          ' position of $ in CellVal
    
    CellVal = Cell.Value
    p = InStr(CellVal, "$") + 1
    If p = 1 Then
        Rental = "No $$$"
    Else
        Rental = Val(Mid(CellVal, p))
    End If
End Function
```

Install the function in a standard code module of your workbook. That's a module you have to insert yourself, by default *Module1*. None of the existing code sheets can do the job.

Call the function from the worksheet with syntax as shown below, where A2 is the cell in which you have your butchered data. You can copy the formula down in the same way as built-in Excel formulas.

```
=Rental(A2)
```

In its present shape the function will look for the $ sign and returns whatever numbers follow it, up till the next non-numeric character or the end of the string. Your system's decimal separator will be deemed numeric but not the thousands separator.

If no $-sign is found the function returns "No $$$". Here the advantage of a UDF comes in. Instead of this you might hitch on another method of looking for the value you want.

Comment: This is a much better solution then what I just came up with which was using a UDF to strip all non-numerical characters out after using find and left to remove text after the second $.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this loop here which should work for your stuff. I couldn't access the link you gave for the file so I tested only with a few random lines I made.

```
Sub ExtractRent()

Dim arr As Variant, lastrow as long, i As Long

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change to suit your range
arr = Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Value 'Change to suit your range

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    DollarSign = InStr(arr(i, 1), "$")
    Range("R" & i) = Val(Mid(arr(i, 1), DollarSign + 1))
Next i

End Sub
```