# I have 55,000 rows of data containing text and numbers and I'm looking to extract only the numbers where possible

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have several thousand data points in excel.

I'm looking to extract only the numbers from the string.

An example of strings may be:

[image]

I want to where possible find the first $ symbol and return the consectutive numbers to the right of it and remove everything else.

I have tried find and replace in VBA which leads to 370,400 becoming the number, or $2,700 (I have used a large variable of find and replace options), however i imagine this could be done with a formula of someone better at data then me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does this problem differ from the problem you posted 1/2 hour earlier?  This one doesn't show what you've tried, nor what you want for a result.

Comment: I was asked to spilt the question into either a formula based question or VBA. Thus this is only in excel formula section and doesn't include the code from the previous post.

Comment: I'd suggest you develop a VBA solution using Regular Expressions (search this forum for VBA and regular expressions for examples) or possibly Power Query.

Comment: I ended up completing it using a UDF and formula for the following expression within the cell "=VALUE(StripChar(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("$",B2)),4),B2)))"

Comment: Depending on what you want, you could probably devise a single regex that processes the entire string.  Might be simpler. But so long as your solution works for you...  BTW, you should be able to mark your answer as "accepted", if not today, then after 24-48 hrs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have 55,000 rows of rental data to clean, the data is inconsistent and contains text and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485521/i-have-55-000-rows-of-rental-data-to-clean-the-data-is-inconsistent-and-contain)

Comment: On your duplcate, you even admit the answer is a better solution than what you came up with...

Answer (score 1):

After looking I ended up having to write a user defined function and include this within an expression as follows:

```
=VALUE(StripChar(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("$",B2)),4),B2)))
```

stripchar UDF is below:

```
Function StripChar(Txt As String) As String 
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 
         .Global = True 
         .Pattern = "\D"
         StripChar = .Replace(Txt, "") 
    End With 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a UDF, then consider:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function NumberGrabber(s As String) As Variant
    Dim arr, L As Long, i As Long, ch As String
    NumberGrabber = ""
    
    If InStr(s, "$") = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    arr = Split(s, "$")
    L = Len(arr(1))
    For i = 1 To L
        ch = Mid(arr(1), i, 1)
        If ch Like "[0-9]" Then
              NumberGrabber = NumberGrabber & ch
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To capture the decimal point and numerals following the decimal point:

```
Public Function NumberGrabber(s As String) As Variant

'    version 3

    Dim arr, L As Long, i As Long, ch As String
    NumberGrabber = ""
    
    If InStr(s, "$") = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    arr = Split(s, "$")
    L = Len(arr(1))
    For i = 1 To L
        ch = Mid(arr(1), i, 1)
        If ch Like "[0-9]" Or ch = "." Then
              NumberGrabber = NumberGrabber & ch
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: You might want to add a dot (decimal) to your character class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach extracting the value, instead of replacing:

```
Function extrRent(S As String)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
        .Global = False 'to extract only the first dollar value
        .Pattern = "\$\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
        If .test(S) Then _
            extrRent = CDbl(.Execute(S)(0).submatches(0))
    End With
End Function
```

If you wanted to return more than just the first instance of a dollar amount, you could modify to return an array of the relevant values.

[image]